# How to tell Listview Selection Mode transitions

Tags: android, listview

Is there a way to know if a user exitted multiple selection mode either by pressing back or unselecting all items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to implement :

```
@Override
public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
    ...
}
```

and

```
@Override
public void onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)  {
    ...
}
```

To detect exiting and entering the multiple selection mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method to register a MultiChoiceModeListener.

```
setMultiChoiceModeListener (AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener listener)
```

This can tell you when the user leaves the multichoice mode.
Not sure about unselecting all items. How does user perform this task?